# field composition vs field extension generated by finite roots

Tags: abstract-algebra

is F(\alpha,\beta) the same field as F(\alpha)F(\beta)?

one containment is obvious but I can't seem to prove the other way :S

Answer (score 1):

$F(\alpha,\beta)$ is the minimal extension containing $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Prove any extension of $F$ that contains $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must also contain $F(\alpha)F(\beta)$ (equivalently, contain $F(\alpha)$ and $F(\beta)$).